# Sql query for the lowest score per country

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a database with 3 tables. In table `country` I have `id` and `name` columns. The `sport` table also has `id` and `name` columns. Finally, the table `match` has `id`, `player1`, and `player2`(that are ids of country that play one against other), `winner_id` (id of country that won the match) and `sport_id` of the sport which was played. The least wins means that I just need in which sport country had the least wins, no matther on played matches.

I want to show the sport per country with the least wins. It should look like this:

| Country | Sport | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Basketball | 2 |

How can I construct this query? I'm using SQL Server.

Data in table look like this. Table countries:

| country_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | France |
| 2 | England |

Table sport:

| sport_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Footbal |
| 2 | Basketball |

Table match:

| match_id | player1 | player2 | winner_id | sport_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 2 |

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Post some sample data and desired query result

Comment: As I said it sould look soometing like this: France 2(worst result) Basketball(in which sport), Netherland 2 Handball and etc.

Comment: Sample data means the data in your source tables and the dataset you want to output from your query - all formatted as tables. You should also update your question with this information, not add it to a comment, so that all the information necessary to help you is in one place

Comment: @NickW,I edited post, can you understand now?

Comment: Still no sample data.

Comment: Sample data doesn't only mean results, but also data from the three tables that would lead to the result. And the task is not crystal clear either. The sports with the least wins are probably those without any wins at all, maybe because the country never participated. Then, what is the result supposed to look like when there is more than one sport for a country with the same minimal result?

Comment: Is this sample data now? @ThorstenKettner

Comment: No, not really, because the sample data doesn't match the result you are showing. Make up some sample data and a *matching* result. But more important: Am I right saying that the sport with least wins is usually the sport the country never participated in? And once more: What about ties, when it's not only one sport with minum wins for a country? ...

Comment: For the current sample data the expected result would be France = Football and Basketball with zero wins each and England = Football and Basketball with zero wins each? How would you want to display these two sports per country? One result row per country and sport, i.e. four result rows?

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that the used wording `with least wins` is not clear, in my solution `with least wins` means `most matches played with least wins`.

To get this ranking, we need to know how many matches a country has played in each sport and how many of those have been won.

```
SELECT 
    country.name AS country,
    sport.name AS sport,
    sport_wins.wins
FROM
    country
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        t.match_count,
        COALESCE(t.wins, 0) AS wins,
        t.sport_id
    FROM (    
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS match_count,
            m_c.sport_id,
            t.wins
        FROM match m_c
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) AS wins,
                match.sport_id
            FROM match
            WHERE country.country_id = match.winner_id 
                  AND match.sport_id = m_c.sport_id
            GROUP BY match.sport_id
        ) t
        WHERE country.country_id IN (m_c.player1, m_c.player2)
        GROUP BY m_c.sport_id, t.wins
    ) t
    ORDER BY t.wins ASC, t.match_count DESC
) sport_wins
JOIN sport ON sport.sport_id = sport_wins.sport_id
```

Please, check [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2007737cc07f44980fc12b884fb9a97).

**If you do not take into account losses, but only the number of wins is of interest**, you can use a query like this one

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        country.country_id,
        sport.sport_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN match.winner_id = country.country_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins
    FROM country
    CROSS JOIN sport
    JOIN match ON match.sport_id = sport.sport_id 
                  AND country.country_id IN (match.player1, match.player2)
    GROUP BY country.country_id, sport.sport_id              
)
SELECT 
    country.name,
    sport.name,
    t.min_wins AS wins
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        country_id,
        MIN(wins) AS min_wins
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY country_id
) t
JOIN cte ON cte.country_id = t.country_id AND cte.wins = min_wins
JOIN country ON cte.country_id = country.country_id
JOIN sport ON cte.sport_id = sport.sport_id
```

This query takes into account the fact that the country participates in matches in sport, so if a country does not compete in a sport, that sport will not be included in the statistics as it will have 0 wins and this will be the minimum value.

Please, check [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e775d0501539ac57b238840e874efd8)

Comment: Thank you. This is the closest answer for my problem. Can you make it to show least wins per country, no matther how many matche thay played

Comment: @Nemanja, i've updated my answer and added an another query

Answer (score 0):

You need to first cross-join the sports with the countries, then get the total.

Then you can use a row-number approach to get the bottom country in each sport

```sql
SELECT
  c.Country,
  c.Sport,
  c.Wins
FROM (
    SELECT
      c.name Country,
      s.name Sport,
      COUNT(m.winner_id) Wins,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sport_id, s.name ORDER BY COUNT(m.winner_id)) rn
    FROM country c
    CROSS JOIN sport s
    LEFT JOIN [match] m
      ON s.sport_id = m.sport_id AND m.winner_id = c.country_id
    GROUP BY
      s.sport_id,
      s.name,
      c.country_id,
      c.name
) c
WHERE c.rn = 1;
```